# Retrieve an object from an array with a specific parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I was wondering whether there is an easy way to select a random object from an array where one of the objects attributes matches a variable.

Something like this:

```
var ninjas = [
    { name: "Sanji Wu", affiliation: "good" },
    { name: "Chian Xi", affiliation: "good" },
    { name: "Chansi Xian", affiliation: "bad" },
    { name: "Chin Chu", affiliation: "bad" },
    { name: "Shinobi San", affiliation: "neutral" },
    { name: "Guisan Hui", affiliation: "neutral" }
];

function getRandom(attr) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * ninjas.length);

    //pseudo code below  
    if (this affiliation is "attr") {
        return a random one that matches
    }
    // end pseudo code
};

var randomItem = getRandom("good");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly straight-forward to create an array with only the matching elements, then grab an entry at random from it:

```
function getRandom(desiredAffiliation) {
    var filtered = ninjas.filter(function(ninja) {
        return ninja.affiliation == desiredAffiliation;
    });
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * filtered.length);
    return filtered[r];
}
```

If you want to make the property you look for a runtime thing, you can do that too, using brackets notation:

```
function getRandom(propName, desiredValue) {
    var filtered = ninjas.filter(function(ninja) {
        return ninja[propName] == desiredValue;
    });
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * filtered.length);
    return filtered[r];
}
```

You'll probably want to tweak those to allow for the possibility there are no matching entries. Right now they'll return `undefined` in that case, since they'll try to return the 0th entry of an array with nothing in it, which isn't an error, but results in the value `undefined`.